deleted template class constructor but there is a specialization behaves differently with clang and gcc
I am trying to understand the behavior.
I am created a template class with a deleted constructor, then I have specialized it for the int type. My goal would be to create instances only for int (specialized) types.
If I initialize template class member with any value it works as expected. Behavior is different with GCC and clang.
https://godbolt.org/z/erYM46ean
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = delete;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << m_what << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T m_what; //{666}; // With this works as expected
};

template<>
Foo<int>::Foo() : m_what{999}
{
    std::cout << "Contructor INT" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> bar;
    bar.print();
    return 0;
}

my expected output would be
Program returned: 0
Contructor INT
999

not like:
Program returned: 0
722345512

Does anyone can give me an explanation? What would be the preferred solution to create an instance with any arbitrary type just for the specialized ones?
Tried: Godbolt, AST, Cpp insight
Goal: avoid creating instances with any arbitrary type allow creation just the specialized ones.

Post code as text

You found a Clang bug, nice job. You can do this e.g. by adding requires to the whole class.

Reported the bug here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/94435

static_assert or SFINAE might be a workaround.

This seems to be another clang bug reported here.
As a workaround you can use requires as shown below:
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo() requires(std::is_same_v<T, int>): m_what(999)
    {
        std::cout << "Contructor INT" << std::endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << m_what << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T m_what; 
};

Demo

I would rather add requires to the whole class.

@HolyBlackCat Yes, but specializing only default ctor looks more close(by looking at their code) to what OP is trying to do.

@HolyBlackCat, unfortunately requires is not available in c++17

@chege54 You should mention this in the question. Both add a c++-17 tag and say this in the text.
